# document.getElementById().onclick not working inside Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, getelementbyid

I am using a cookie consent management service, calling it via Google Tag Manager (custom HTML tag). Their script has function `CookieControl.open();` which opens a sidebar to allow users to change their preferences.

```
<script src="https://cc.cdn.civiccomputing.com/9/cookieControl-9.x.min.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {
...
...
...
};

CookieControl.load(config);

window.onload = function () {
    var cookiesExist = document.querySelector('#cookies');
    if (cookiesExist) {
        document.getElementById("cookies").onclick =
            function () {
                CookieControl.open();
            };
    }
};
</script>
```

In my footer, I have added a link `<a id="cookies">Cookies</a>` which the function in GTM is supposed to target. Unfortunately this is not working and the sidebar does not open when I click on the "Cookies" link. It does sometimes work, randomly, on Safari on the iPad. But it's not consistent.
Any ideas why most of the time this doesn't work (but other times it does)?

Comment: Have you verified (via a simply console.log or something), that your function executes at all? Using `window.onload = …` is dangerous, this can easily get overwritten by other script functionality. You should rewrite that to properly use addEventListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example.

// https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-leaf-vznep?file=/src/index.js

We attached a click event listener to the button, added an href attribute and prevent its default behavior by using the `e.preventDefault` function. We also created a dedicated function for the `CookieControl.open()` method.

You may need to wrap the script inside this event listener to make sure that the document is ready before attaching the click event listener to the button.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
    // move the content of index.js file here
});
```

UPDATE: Duplicated the script in the stackoverflow sandbox in case the link above expires.

```js
import "./styles.css";

// load cookie control

function openCookieControl(e) {
  console.log("CookieControl open");
  // CookieControl.open();
}

let button = document.getElementById("cookies");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  openCookieControl();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="#" id="cookies">Cookies</a>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```